# Check if DLL uses SSE instructions

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, dll, x86, sse

I am cross-compiling a C++ application with Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 7 (target platform = Windows XP Embedded).  The target CPU does not support SSE or SSE2 instructions.  I therefore would like to be able to double-check that the DLLs and EXEs that I build do not use any SSE or SSE2 instructions.  How can I do this?

Comment: No point in double-checking when you can simply set the compile option correctly.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx /arch compiler option.

Comment: @HansPassant I know about that compile option and I am using it. However, I noticed that our own build of QtCore4.dll crashed on the target platform due to an illegal instruction. After checking with OllyDbg it turned out that it still had SSE instructions inside, although I configured Qt 4.8.6 with the -no-sse and -no-sse2 options. I am now trying to understand why the DLL still has SSE instructions. I am trying to track down where in our Qt build we are forgetting the /arch:IA32 option. I plan to write some kind of script, hence this post.

Comment: `objdump -d | grep xmm` might be a good first approximation.

Comment: It'll be hard to avoid false positives on code that does runtime CPU detection, and selects what version of things to run based on what the CPU supports.  So there can be SSE and AVX code in the binary, but it still works fine on whatever the baseline is.

Comment: Some compilers use SSE/SSE2 for scalar FP math, even in 32bit binaries.  e.g. `float` uses SSE, `double` uses SSE2.  `mulsd` = FP multiply scalar double-precision.  (`mulpd` = packed double, i.e. SIMD vector instead of just the low element in the vector register.)

Comment: [How to check if a binary requires SSE4 or AVX on Linux](https://superuser.com/q/726395/241386), [How to check if compiled code uses sse and avx instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47878352/995714)

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can do it quick and dirty:

1. Run Visual Studio command prompt
2. Call `dumpbin /disasm required.dll > dll_disasm.asm`
3. Look for common SSE/SSE2 instructions, e.g. `movss`, `xmm0` or `xmm1`

If no SSE instruction/registers found in DLL, you're good unless the DLL loads something else.